# What limits are there on the property that $a \space \ln(i) = \ln(i^a) $

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, logarithms

For what values does the property $a \space \ln(i) = \ln(i^a) $ hold? I found to my dismay that $ 4 \ln(i) $ was not returning the same results as $ \ln(i^4) = 0$. In addition, does there exist a log base where if $a$ is a multiple of $4$, and a base $b$ is chosen, then  $ a \space \log_b(i) = \log_b(i^4) = 0$? Alternatively, is there another function $f$ of the form $a \space f(i) = f(i^a) $ that exists? I would be eager to know about either option.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There's nothing to be gained by changing bases, since that just amounts to scaling the natural logarithm: $\log_b c = \frac{\log c}{\log b}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we write a function $z \mapsto b^z$ in the context of complex analysis, we mean $$z \mapsto \exp(z \log b) ,$$ but as you know $\log$ has infinitely many branches (owing to the fact that $\exp$ is periodic), and so our function depends on our choice of branch for $\log$. Correspondingly, so do the values for which, e.g., $\log(i^a) = a \log i$ holds.

**Example** Consider the branch of $\log$ with imaginary part in $\left[0, 2 \pi \right)$. Then $\log i = \frac{\pi i}{2}$, so $4 \log i = 2 \pi i$, which is not in the codomain of our branch, hence we cannot have $4 \log i = \log(i^4)$. On the other hand, for real $a$ such that $\Im(a \log i) \in [0, 2 \pi)$, that is, $a \in [0, 4)$, the identity $\log(i^a) = a \log i$ does hold.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for specifying. Two noob questions. 1. I'm *very* new to complex analysis, I've just begun reading Visual Complex Analysis by Needham, so I'm not entirely familiar with these branches yet. Any quick reading resources/websites would be highly valuable, should you know any places. 2. Do you happen to know (offhand) if there is any way to extend or change $\Im(a \space \log{i}) $ in a programming environment to allow any arbitrary integer value of $a$ to satisfy the desired property? Is there any mathematical consequence or "penalty" of doing this? All the best.

Comment: @Nate Try this out! https://complex-analysis.com/

Comment: @Nate There's no function that lets you recover $a$ from $i^a$: If $a f(i) = f(i^a)$ for all real numbers $a$ (for some fixed choice of $\log$) then $0 f(i) = f(i^0) = f(1) = f(i^4) = 4 f(i)$, so $f(i) = 0$ and hence $f(i^a) = a f(i) = 0$ for all $a$. What is it that you're trying to achieve? (Your question may be an instance of the XY problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem )

Answer (score 0):

The property $a\ln(i) = \ln(i^a)$ or more generally, $a\ln(z) = \ln(z^a)$ for any $z\in\mathbb C$, is true only for the Principal Branch of the Complex Logarithm.

This is due to the fact that the  complex Logarithm is a multi-valued function. In $\mathbb C$, a *branch* of the (complex) logarithm is generally defined as
$$\log z=\{\ln|z|+i\arg(z)+2\pi ik\ :\ k\in\mathbb Z \}.$$
Clearly, this is neither analytic nor even continuous at 0. To get rid of this problem and obtain an *analytic branch* of the logarithm, we often use
$$\operatorname{Log} z:= \ln|z|+i\operatorname{Arg}(z),$$ where $\operatorname{Arg}(\cdot)$ denotes the Principal Argument. This branch is commonly called the **Principal Branch**.

It is this branch of the logarithm that satisfies all nice properties of the usual (real) logarithm such as:

- $\operatorname{Log}(zw) =\operatorname{Log}z + \operatorname{Log}w $.
- $\operatorname{Log}(z^a)=a\operatorname{Log}(z)$. Etc.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm using i as my default value, so since the length of i is simply 1, that means that ln|(1|) = 0. Then the only thing that I would worry about it i * Arg(z), right? In that instance, would $ln(i^2)$ for instance be written as i * Arg(z^2), and, without loss of generality, i * Arg(i^2)? I'm running into issues getting a numerical match within the Julia programming language, so I will probably go to a coding forum to straighten the rest of this out.

Comment: The claim at the end of the answer isn't true. The principal branch of the argument function takes values in $(-\pi, \pi]$, so, e.g., $\operatorname{Log} [(-1)^2] = \operatorname{Log} 1 = 0$ but $2 \operatorname{Log} (-1) = 2 (\pi i) = 2 \pi i$.

Comment: I generally take the principal branch with the cut of the negative real axis and 0 and the principal Argument to be in the open interval. With that convention the above issue may be resolved.

Comment: @Nate I think you meant to say $\ln{|i|} = \ln{1} = 0$. And if we're treating $\ln{}$ as the complex definition on any general  branch, then $\ln{\left(i^2\right)} = \ln{\left|i^2\right|} + i\text{arg}\left(i^2\right) = 0 + i(\pi + 2n\pi) = i(\pi + 2n\pi)$. The value of $\log{z}$ depends on what branch you choose.

Comment: @sadman-ncc Even if one omits the negative real axis from the branch, OP's example still shows that the claim in general is false: $\operatorname{Log}(i^4) = \operatorname{Log} 1 = 0$ but $4 \operatorname{Log} i = 4 \cdot \frac{\pi i}{2} = 2 \pi i$.